# ANOVA on a normally and a log-normally distributed variable: what to transform?

Tags: anova, normalization, lognormal-distribution

For an analysis of variance the residuals (but not the data?) have to be normally distributed.

So, I have two variables, one is normally distributed, one is log-normally distributed, and their residuals are log-normally distributed. To perform the anova, what do I log-transform: the residuals or the values of the log-normally distributed variable or the values of both variables?

Comment: How do you plan to transform the residuals in order to perform an ANOVA when, in order to obtain the residuals, you have to perform the ANOVA *first*?

Comment: @whuber So, if I understand you corretly, the procedure is to perform an ANOVA, test the residuals for normality, and, if they are not normally distributed, transform the data, do the ANOVA again, reevaluate the residuals, and if they are now normally distributed, interpret the results?

Comment: That is exactly the right way to use ANOVA for data exploration and description.  If you intend to apply formal hypothesis tests, though, you must adjust them for the loss of degrees of freedom induced by the all models you fit during that process.